# Exposing a Publish/Subscribe Message Queue to the Internet

Tags: security, push-notification, redis, message-queue, nonblocking

I have been very interested in using a message queue (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, redis, etc.) with publish/subscribe so that I can send push messages to clients. In reality I need clients to be able to subscribe from the open Internet and the MQ host to be the only one that can publish. But the problem seems to be that none of the solutions that exist were designed to be used on the open Internet due to their inherently open nature and all suggest being put behind a firewall/frontend which breaks the usefulness of the MQ (firewall would prevent the clients from changing IP and a frontend like a REST API wouldn't allow for subscribing and would essentially turn push into poll).

So is there any solutions/alternatives to this problem that would allow me to do this? And is a message queue the correct solution (I looked into using nonblocking sockets, but I would rather avoid having to deal with raw sockets)?

Answer (score 2):

I am looking into something similar and did search for an opensource solution with no success. My current solution is to have a Restful interface for publish and subscribing messages. I am using java to implement it and created a Rest resource to allow clients to register a HTTP endpoint which in itself can be a rest resource which accepts post messages. Once the client registered his intent to subscribe to a specific resource and provided the Rest endpoint, I have use a RabbitMq direct exchange to route messages to queues which in turn trigger a post message to all subscribers.

This solution did work for me and you can try the same model.

I have used the java Observer pattern to listen to new messages on the queue and trigger new http requests.

As this is a rest based implementation you can implement this in any language.